# Function returning the same index all the time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of float values inside the dictionary. It's content looks like that:

```
dic['area'] = [12.3, 3.7, 9.43, -1, -1, 55.32, 72.6]
```

Positions with -1 are former strings (? and -) that couldn't be converted into float. I wrote function that should return me indexes of those negative values:

```
def find_index(x,y):
    for item in x:
        if item < 0:
            index = x.index(item)
            y.append(index)
        else:
            continue
    print (y)
```

Where x is dic['area'] list and y is empty list. Unfortunately, using that function on

```
dic['area'] = [12.3, 3.7, 9.43, -1, -1, 55.32, 72.6]
```

Would return me:

```
[3, 3]
```

and every next value that is smaller than 0 will cause appending to the y list another 3. Why is it happenning?

Comment: `.index(..)` always returns the **first match in `x`**...

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what `index` does; returns the index of the first item that matches.

Instead, you should keep a counter when you iterate, using `enumerate`:

```
for i, item in enumerate(x):
    if item < 0:
        y.append(i)
```

Note, the whole thing could be written better as a list comprehension:

```
print([i for i, item in enumerate(x) if item < 0])
```